# Return all locales for selected field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Say I have a model Book

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, localize: true
  # ... much more fields
end
```

Now I want to query for only name only, but for all locales. Book.only(:name) seems to return the current locale, and while I could do Book.only(:name, :"name.ar"), it requires that I manually add all locales I have.

Is there a way to tell Mongoid I want all locales of selected field?